# How to use 'refresh' flag in LoadCollectionParam properly?

Tags: milvus

In the code I found the next comment:

```
// refresh:
//   This flag must be set to FALSE when first time call the loadCollection().
//   After loading a collection, call loadCollection() again with refresh=TRUE,
//   the server will look for new segments that are not loaded yet and tries to load them up.
```

**Questions**:

1. How do I know when a new segment is added? Setting `refresh` to `true`
   slows down the search significantly. That's why I want to do it when it's
   actually necessary.
2. Do I need to load collection before every search? If not, when?

I use `milvus-sdk-java 2.2.9`